# Possibility of foreach in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreach

I'm currently having a problem in SQL.

I have two tables. The first one contains an int value and the int ID of an account and the second one contains some userdata and the value, I want to update.

1. table:

   ```
   TABLE (INT AccountID, INT ValueToAdd)
   ```
2. table:

   ```
   TABLE (INT AccountID, INT ValueToBeUpdated, ...)
   ```

I want SQL to look through the 1. table which `AccountID` it needs from the 2. table and should then update the `ValueToBeUpdated` value where the `1.table.AccountID = 2.table.AccountID`

I hope you get what I mean. I didn't find a way to do this in a set-orientated language like SQL yet, as I cant do foreach loops through one of the tables like here:

```
foreach (row in 2.table)
{
  if (row.AccountID IN 1.table.AccountID)
  {
     UPDATE row SET ValueToBeUpdated = (SELECT ValueToAdd FROM 1.table WHERE AccountID = row.AccountID)
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me out :)

Comment: You are thinking of a looping structure.  Think of SQL more like set-based operations.  For this one, you can actually join to other tables within an `UPDATE` command.  Check this closely duplicated answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: `WHILE` loops and iterative solutions using cursors are possible in `sql` but should always be avoided if a set based solution is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget looping, You could do like this for your case :

```
UPDATE
    row
SET
    r.ValueToBeUpdated.col1 = t.ValueToAdd
FROM
    row r
INNER JOIN
    table t
ON
    t.AccountID = r.AccountID
```

**References**

[Why are relational set-based queries better than cursors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168/why-are-relational-set-based-queries-better-than-cursors)

[Understanding “Set based” and “Procedural” approaches in SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches)

Comment: Okay I have a complex select query to data of the 1.table cause that results of 3 INNER JOINs already. But I made myself a temporary table now where I first stored that data in and now you suggestion works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is easily execute without using foreach loop.

```
UPDATE table2 SET ValueToBeUpdated = a.ValueToAdd
FROM table2 b INNER JOIN table1 a 
ON a.AccountID = b.AccountID
```

Comment: Why not use a JOIN? This is artificially hard to understand. It is like a code obfuscation contest entry.