# Cursor through and update database record by looking for value within a range from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like this:

**Table1**

```
Emp_ID    Emp_Name     Age Level
1         Tom          22
2         Susan        50
```

**Table2**

```
Level     Min_Age      Max_Age
Associate   20            30
Senior      31            45
```

What I want to do is to find which level each employee is at. As such, I want to:

Do for all records in Table1 (All employees)
i.  Select Level from Table2 where Table1.Age is between Min_Age and Max_Age in Table2
ii.Move to next employee

I have tried the following:

```
DECLARE @level int, DECLARE @employee_age int
DELCARE  @min_age varcahr int, @max_age varchar int
DECLARE testcursor CURSOR 

LOCAL SCROLL STATIC

FOR

Select Emp_ID FROM Table1

OPEN testcursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM testcursor 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

   FETCH NEXT FROM testcursor

   @min_age=select Min_age from Table2
   @max_age= select Max_age from Table2

   @employee_age=Select age FROM Table1

   @level=select Level from Table2 where 

   update Table1 set level=@level where @employee_age between @min_age and max_age

END

CLOSE cursorName

DEALLOCATE cursorName
```

This doesn't completely work since I have to cursor through the records in Table2 as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to use a cursor at all. Just join the two tables together.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[age level] = t2.level
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.[age level] BETWEEN t2.min_age and t2.max_age
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join- or you can use the following

```
BEGIN
   for i in (select level, [min age] as MinA, [max age] as MaxA from Table2)
LOOP 
Update Table1
   set Table1.[age level] = i.level
   where Table1.[age level] between i.MinA and i.MaxA;
END LOOP;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by SQLChao, this operation is better done with a set-based approach rather than looping through all the rows and updating them individually.

This is for both performance and readability.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[level] = t2.level
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.[age] BETWEEN t2.min_age and t2.max_age
```

Have a read of this question, one of many on here outlining the reasons for using set-based queries wherever possible:
[Why are relational set-based queries better than cursors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168/why-are-relational-set-based-queries-better-than-cursors)