# How to parse a row returned from a T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table (lets call it Audit) in SQL Server

```
AuditID int primary not null,
Name varchar(300),
AuditCount int,
ActualCount int,
AuditDate datetime
```

The table could have any number of rows with a given AuditID in it. I want to iterate through the table, given an AuditID, and compare the AuditCount with the ActualCount. If they are not equal, then I'll do something else...but first, how do I retrieve one row at a time, and compare the values returned?

Comment: You can iterate through one row at a time, but most people would use a set-based query to do this in SQL.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168/why-are-relational-set-based-queries-better-than-cursors.

Comment: You'll have to specify more concretely what *do something* might be: insert a record? delete a record? create a table? sum something?

Comment: is my answer helpful. If so mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    AuditID,
    Name,
    AuditCount,
    ActualCount,
    AuditDate
FROM Audit
WHERE AuditCount <> ActualCount;
```

or

```
SELECT
        AuditID,
        Name,
        case when AuditCount <> ActualCount then 'Do something'
        else 'do something else' end as myColumn,
        AuditDate
FROM Audit;
```