# How to loop in a database and perform certain operations?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Table 1:

| product_name | brands | Supplier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz |  | Adidas |
| abc |  | Nike |

Table 2:

| brands | keys | Suppliers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | x, y,z | Puma,Adidas |
| A | a | New Balance |

What I want to do is check if t1.product_name contains any t2.keys, if it does add t2.brands to t1.brands.

Code in python:

```
for index, key in enumerate(keys):
    for sub_index, sub_key in enumerate(key):

       for i, name in enumerate(product_name):

          if sub_key in name:
               Table1["brands"][i] =  Table1["brands"][index]
```

**My questions:**

1. Is this possible in SQL?
2. Is there a way I can use this script in SQL instead?

Comment: Well, probably. To find out for sure, create a https://dbfiddle.uk/ with some sample data and update your post with the url and expected result. Never mind that the DBMS is not there, from the sound of it it should be possible with standard sql that will work in all DBMS

Comment: You can write loops, the question is do you want this? Consider a set based approach, this requires a different way of thinking about your problem but it will beat cursors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168/why-are-relational-set-based-queries-better-than-cursors

Comment: Snowflake is not SQL Server - please tag your RDBMS correctly. And as already said while can you loop (and there are plenty of tutorials and documentation out there), its very rare that you need to. Set based is what you should be aiming for.

Comment: You can do this in a single statement, but unclear which platform you are using: Snowflake or SQL Server?

Comment: I am using Snowflake @Charlieface.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single statement. In Snowflake you can do it like this:

```sql
UPDATE Table1
SET brands = (
    SELECT LISTAGG(t2.brands, ', ')
    FROM Table2 AS t2
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t2.keys, ',') AS s
        WHERE Table1.product_name LIKE '%' || TRIM(s.value) || '%'
    )
);
```

In SQL Server you would do it like this:

```sql
UPDATE t1
SET brands = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(t2.brands, ', ')
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(t2.keys, ',') s
        WHERE t1.product_name LIKE '%' + TRIM(s.value) + '%'
    )
)
FROM Table1 t1;
```

Comment: How would you work on this problem now @Charlieface? I have added one extra dimension. If supplier from t2.suppliers match t1.supplier, then set t1. brands = t2.brands

Comment: I suggest you post that as a new question. But you probably shouldn't be storing multiple pieces of information in a single column anyway

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Table 2 which has multiple values is a table that I want to use only to map Brand name for product name in table1. Other than that it doesnot has any use.